# Problem with creating a filter button to filter rendered cards in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an app that fetches data from a server and renders it in cards, i'm creating a filter functionality to filter cards based on repository main language, the functionality technically works, when you press on 'Javascript' option for example it only shows repos with javascript, but the problem is after that if you press 'All' or any other option it assumes this list of only javascript items is the real state, even though i'm not directly mutating the data state which stores all the fetched repositories, i'd appreciate any help in understanding what's going on, you'll find the component code below.

```
class MainSection extends Component {
  state = {
    data: null,
    filteredData: null,
    loading: true,
    filterLanguages: null,
    slideText: false,
    currentFilter: 'All'
  }
  async componentDidMount() {
    try {
      // eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
      const resp = await axios
        .get("https://backendkham.herokuapp.com/api/show")
        .then((response) => {
          const finalLangs = ["All"];
          const languages = response.data.data.forEach((element) => {
            element.repos.forEach((repo) => {
              // console.log(repo.languages)
              finalLangs.push(repo.languages);
            });
          });
          const validData = response.data.data.filter(
            (user) => user.repos.length > 0
          );
          this.setState(prevState => ({
            ...prevState,
            data: [...validData],
            filteredData: [...validData],
            loading: false,
            filterLanguages: [...new Set(finalLangs)].filter((item) => item)
          }))
        });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      return Promise.reject(error);
    }
  }
  
  render() {

  
    const filterRepos = (lang) => {
    // console.log(lang)
        if (lang === "All") {
      this.setState(prevState => ({
        filteredData: prevState.data
      }))
        } else {
            const dataToBeFiltered = [...this.state.data].map((obj) => {
                // console.log(obj.repos);
                obj.repos = obj.repos.filter((repo) => repo.languages === lang);
        // console.log(obj.repos);
                return obj;
            });
            this.setState(prevState => ({
        ...prevState, 
        filteredData: dataToBeFiltered
      }))
      console.table(this.state);
            // console.log(filteredData);
            // console.log(dataToBeFiltered);
        }
  };
  const newFilter = (repoLang) => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      ...prevState, 
      currentFilter: repoLang
    }))
  } 
  const animateFilterOptions = () => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      ...prevState,
      slideText: !prevState.slideText
    }))
  }
    if (this.state.loading) {
        return (
            <Loader
                className={classes.Loader}
                type="TailSpin"
                color="#00BFFF"
                height={100}
                width={100} //3 secs
            />
        );
    }
    if (this.state.data) {
    // console.log('filter languages are:', typeof(filterLanguages[0]));
    // console.log('data in render method:', data)
        return (
            <>
                <Filter
                    filterRepos={(event) => filterRepos(event.target.value)}
                    slideText={this.state.slideText}
                    btnClick={animateFilterOptions}
                    languages={this.state.filterLanguages}
                />
                <div className={classes.Main}>
                    <Cards data={this.state.filteredData} />
                </div>
            </>
        );
  }
}
};
```

Comment: You want to be defining your callbacks outside of `render()`.  But you don't *need* to be storing the `filteredData` in state at all, you can just filter it and print the results.

Comment: Found the issue! It's a deep/shallow copy thing.  I'll write an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The source of your problem is that you are inadvertently mutating state in this section:

```
const dataToBeFiltered = [...this.state.data].map((obj) => {
   obj.repos = obj.repos.filter((repo) => repo.languages === lang);
   return obj;
});
```

Both `.map()` and `[...this.state.data]` will create a copy of your array.  However it is a shallow copy where the array itself is a new array, but the elements of that array are object references to the same objects as before.  So you when you mutate those objects, you mutate them in every place -- including in the original `this.state.data` array.

Try this instead:

```
const dataToBeFiltered = this.state.data.map((obj) => {
  return {
    ...obj,
    repos: obj.repos.filter((repo) => repo.languages === lang)
  };
});
```

We return a new object where all of the properties of `obj` are copied (shallowly) via `...obj` and then the `repos` property is overwritten.  You could just write `=> ({ _ })` instead of `=> { return { _ }; }` if you want.

Comment: You're a lifesaver Linda!  i just searched about shallow/deep copying after your first comment, i found out i can also use "JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(object))" to create a deep copy that's detached from the original one, but i'll be using yours because this one's quite ugly :D, thank you so much.

Comment: Yeah it's not necessary to create a deep copy because any properties which you aren't changing can stay the same and it's no issue, you just need to make sure that you are never mutating anything and always making changes by returning copies.  You will see this `...` syntax used for this purpose a lot.  FYI `.map()` and `.filter()` both return copies so they are safe to use.